# Change User locale but keep all settings for English (U.S.) in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, language, matlab, locale

I'd like to be able to display Russian characters in MATLAB. As described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/66-how-can-i-display-russian-cyrillic-characters-in-a-figure-in-matlab-7-7-r2008b) I have to change both User and System Locales to Russian. And yes, it works!

The problem is since I'm in US I don't want to use the default setting in Russian user locale for Numbers, Date, Time, etc. Well, I can set most of them back to US, but not days of the week and month names that are now in Russian.

Any advice how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

applocale is an application which helps you simulate a locale change the locale for a specific application. So if you follow user88311's suggestion your mathlab will run in Russian settings while everything else in the OS will stay as they are today. You can set up a shortcut in applocale to do this quickly everytime.

Check this for installation instructions on Windows 7 - http://www.emreakkas.com/windows-tips/how-to-install-applocale-on-windows-7

See this one for usage instructions and tips - http://www.emreakkas.com/localization-tools/how-to-use-applocale

Comment: No link, plus since you're just adding to *user88311*'s answer, why not add a comment to it instead?

Comment: @eakkas: This makes it clearmuch more. I think it's good to keep your answer. I'll google, but some link would be useful for future readers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Karan, perhaps it is due my profile being new, I am not able to add a comment on user8831's answer. That's why I needed to submit a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use applocale to run your browser in russian while leaving your locale to US english.

EDIT: Somehow I missed your last line of text, please state your OS and I can provide you with details how to.

EDIT 2 : By the days of week, months, etc, I assume you are referring to things like your computers calender?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer. I set Windows 7 as a tag. I have to change both System and User locales to Russian for MATLAB to work. I need days of week and months to show correctly (in English) in MS Office, for example.